# Auto detect and display available wifi while opening chrome plugin

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, wifi

We are going to develop a plugin in chrome which is going to use in HP chrome box.Once we connected the respective HP chrome box to any device it should automatically open the wifi setting and it should detect the available wifi's and it should display those list.

Please Suggest the methods or ideas which will be useful for our implementation